# Reactive Native: How to modify the stylesheet directly to a file provided?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

I want to change the 'bottomBorderColor' from

https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/blob/master/DefaultTabBar.js#L75

at the bottom of the page.

Tried like so but does not work unfortunately:

```
    <ScrollableTabView
      style={{borderBottomColor: 'white'}}
    >
      <Text tabLabel='Tab1'> Test 1 </Text>
      <Text tabLabel='Tab2'> Test 2 </Text>
      <Text tabLabel='Tab3'> Test 3 </Text>
    </ScrollableTabView>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to apply the `borderBottomWidth` property. You need to do as following:

```js
<ScrollableTabView
  style={{borderBottomColor: 'white', borderBottomWidth: 3}}
>
  <Text tabLabel='Tab1'> Test 1 </Text>
  <Text tabLabel='Tab2'> Test 2 </Text>
  <Text tabLabel='Tab3'> Test 3 </Text>
</ScrollableTabView>
```

Comment: Tried it out but unfortunately no go... Should it be done some other way?